# comparing nested arrays for equality

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given the following arrays:

```
$array[0]['tid'] = 'valueX';
$array[1]['tid'] = 'valueY';

$array2[0]['tid'] = 'valueZ';
$array2[1]['tid'] = 'valueY';
```

My goal is to check if any of the values in `$array` are in `$array2`

Below is what I came up with but I'm wondering if there is a easier / better solution?
Maybe something that gets only the values of an array or removes the `'tid'` key.

```
foreach($array as $arr) {
    $arr1[] = $arr['tid'];
}

$flag = 0;

foreach($array2 as $arr) {
    if( in_array( $arr['tid'], $arr1 ) ) {
        $flag++;
    }
}
echo $flag; // number of duplicates
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could approach this:

```
$extractor = function($row) { return $row['tid']; };
echo "Duplicates: ".count(array_intersect(
    array_map($extractor, $array),
    array_map($extractor, $array2)
));
```

What this does is pull out the `tid` value from each array element on both arrays, then intersecting the results (to find values present in both arrays). It might make sense to tweak it a bit or keep the interim results around depending on what exactly you intend to do.

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OvdzbU).

Comment: thanks this is great! exacly what I was looking for! didn't know you could use functions this way +1

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to pull values from the arrays.

The transformed arrays could then be looped with the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function. Better, you could use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) which will return the elements common to both transformed arrays.

You may also find that [flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array) your array can sometimes yield a quick and dirty solution, though PHP does not (to my knowledge) have a built in function for this the linked posted has several variants.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want how many are matching the code you have posted will work

You could try using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to pull the values

`array_map(function($array){return $array['tid']}, $inputArray())`

Comment: Accept Jon's answer, he finished before me ;-)