# Easiest way to determine if a key/value is identical in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[items] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 1
            [class] => P
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 1
            [class] => P
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 1
            [class] => S
        )

)
```

What is the easiest way to determine if the [class] value is the same in all internal arrays? Am I going to have to loop through all of them and compare one by one? Or is there a better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [a better sollution to compare / check if value of nested array is in other nested array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476200/a-better-sollution-to-compare-check-if-value-of-nested-array-is-in-other-neste)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit based on comments**

*Solution to check of equality based on `class` comparison only*

```
$n = count($array['items']);
$elem = $array['items'][0]['class'];

for ($i=1 ; $i<$n ; $i++) 
   if ($elem !== $array['items'][$i]['class']) 
       break;

if ($i >= $n) {
    // equal
}
```

Features

- At most N-1 ($n-1) comparisons
- Using `!==` and not `!=` to check for perfect match (type and value)
- Set `elem` to the first element `[0]`, so that PHP doesn't have to fetch it all the time

---

*Solution to test if internal arrays are equal*

Use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) that returns the difference between arrays.

For instance, to compare N arrays in `[items]` (does at most N-1 comparisons)

```
$n = count($array['items']);
for($i=1 ; $i<$n ; $i++) 
   if (count(array_diff($array['items'][0], $array['items'][$i])))
      break;

if ($i >= $n) {
     // they are equal
}
```

`array_diff()` returns elements that are *not* in the arrays being compared. Counting the elements returned (`count()`) allows to detect differences.

Note that `array_diff()` can take more than two arrays to check for equality. If you have a fixed number of arrays, you can simply do

```
// Compare 3 arrays
if (count(array_diff($array['items'][0], $array['items'][1], $array['items'][2]))) {
    // Arrays differ
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work, because you're testing each entire internal array against each other. I need to test specifically for the value of one key in each array. For example, if I add one element to the first internal array, it breaks. [Here's an example](http://codepad.org/K8L0rClz)

Comment: Updated my answer so that you have two solutions.

Comment: Thanks. So basically, as I originally asked, there's no way other than looping through the arrays to do this comparison.

Comment: Of course you could check `if (A && B && C)` but if the number of items is unknown or large, and since you test a single value among other elements, a one by one check is necessary, in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = count($array['items']);
$flag=0;
for($i=0 ; $i<$n ; $i++)
{
  if($i!=0)
  {
       if($array['items'][$i][class]!=$array['items'][$i-1][class])
       {
              $flag=1;
        }
  }

}

if($flag==1)
{
  // they are equal
}
```

Comment: So the answer is yes - I'm going to have to loop through them all. That's all I needed if there wasn't a better way.

Comment: This also doesn't work if the class element is in a different position in each array. See [this example](http://codepad.org/rEQcxfr3).